# populating listview programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to display the contacts stored on the emulator in a listview. Later on though it will be just a set of selected contacts stored by the app (need a suggestion for this  storage and retrieval). Since the list cannot be a hard coded string array i have tried to fill the listview programmatically but i am getting an error.

here's the code PS: beginner android dev.

I have included the necessary permissions in manifest Reads_contacts.. so that's not a problem

```
public class settings_manager extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.setting);
   TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
   th.setup();

   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   final Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


   TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
   spec1.setIndicator("CONTACTS");
   if(!cur.moveToNext()){
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1); 
    }
   else{
    spec1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            ListView contacts_list = new ListView(settings_manager.this);
            String[] c_list = null; int i=0;
            while(cur.moveToNext())
            {
                   int nameindex = cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                   c_list[i] = cur.getString(nameindex); i++;

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> contacts_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(null,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c_list);
            return contacts_list;
        }
    }) ; 

  }
   th.addTab(spec1);


   TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
   spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
   spec2.setIndicator("tab2");
   th.addTab(spec2);


   TabSpec spec3 = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
   spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
   spec3.setIndicator("tab3");
   th.addTab(spec3);
}
```

The log cat has to say this :i'm not really sure what indicates what so i'm pasting the entire thing

```
    03-05 22:57:18.185: D/AndroidRuntime(232): Shutting down VM
    03-05 22:57:18.185: W/dalvikvm(232): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught                                                           exception (group=0x4001b188)
    03-05 22:57:18.185: E/AndroidRuntime(232): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception 
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{water.tank/water.tank.settings_manager}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512) 
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at water.tank.settings_manager$1.createTabContent(settings_manager.java:47)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.widget.TabHost$FactoryContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:617)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at water.tank.settings_manager.onCreate(settings_manager.java:57)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
    03-05 22:57:18.195: E/AndroidRuntime(232):  ... 11 more
    03-05 22:57:18.215: I/dalvikvm(232): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    03-05 22:57:18.215: E/dalvikvm(232): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Firstly Aseem, your question is not clear. Add more details of the issue you are facing. Also can you add the logcat info to this question. It will be easier to find out what is happening. Btw have you added the `READ_CONTACTS` permission in the AndroidManifest.xml in your project?

Comment: i have mentioned about the permission already - yes i have included that.

Comment: Ok. What does the logcat say when the app crashes?

Comment: As the log says, you have a NullPointer in your createTabContent() method at line 47, so make sure everything is initialized and has a value.

Comment: i have tried everything.. i missed out to set the adapter to the list which i have done now but i still face some error..the entire code's there..could you please point out where i'm wrong.

Comment: is this got to do with some problem with emulator not able to mimic the phone due to some missing code..? i don't see any tutorial that displays contacts in a list

Answer (score 1):

There were many mistakes in your code. NPE was only the first.

```
//Prevented cursor moving forward unnecessorily.
if (cur.getCount() == 0) {
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
} else {
    spec1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            ListView contacts_list = new ListView(settings_manager.this);

            String[] c_list = new String[cur.getCount()];//NPE was here.

            // use cur.getPosition() instead of int i = 0; i++;
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                c_list[cur.getPosition()] = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> contacts_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    null, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c_list);

            //set listadaper
            contacts_list.setAdapter(contacts_adapter);
            return contacts_list;
        }
    });
}
```